# Is there a shorter way of accomplishing this task in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach (var item in todos)
    {
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="item.IsDone"/>
            @if(item.IsDone){
                <span style="text-decoration: line-through">@item.Title</span>
            }else{
                <span>@item.Title</span>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>

<input placeholder="Something todo" @bind="newTodo"/>
<button @onclick="AddTodo">Add todo</button>
```

I want the style to apply when an item is checked, but in a more concise way using only data binding without the 'if' statement.

Comment: OK, those who voted to close this question could do what I've done: Just remove the word 'better' from the title. Now this question is legitimate and not opinion-based, and thus should not be closed...

Comment: I agree. Hear hear!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this...

In your ToDo class definition add a new field named

```
 public string Style => IsDone ? "text-decoration: line-through" : "";
```

And the usage would be:

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="item.IsDone"/>
<span style="@item.Style">@item.Title</span>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

According to [Conditional HTML element attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#conditional-html-element-attributes)

> HTML element attributes are conditionally rendered based on the .NET
> value. If the value is false or null, the attribute isn't rendered. If
> the value is true, the attribute is rendered minimized.

So that you can use inline condition, (assuming this works, I haven't tried this):

```
<span style="@item.IsDone ? "text-decoration: line-through" : null">@item.Title</span>
```

Comment: Interesting enet's implementation would work the same if the conditional returned a null?
I would prefer to conditionally apply a class however but this coding style.